# SymmetricDS conditional sync

Tags: java, symmetricds

I need to set up conditional sync via SymmetricDS. I know I can use columns to determine if the entry is being synced, but I need to determine it via external table. Is there a way to do that?

I.e. I have entries with `project_id` in one table, and table, that says which users are on which project, and I need user to receive his projects only.

Also, as a side-question, is there a way to dynamically change synchronization rules (or change them at all after I first started it)?

Answer (score 0):

try the subselect router as explained here: http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.1/html/configuration.html#configuration-subselect-router